# How to run C and Mathematica repeatedly?

Tags: external-calls

I use a C program to generate a ".txt" file, and import this ".txt" file into Mathematica to do some calculations and export these calculations.

Due to limitation of data size in C program, I have to repeatedly

1.run a "*.out" program on terminal (which generates some random data I needed);

2.run the Mathematica program manually on Mathematica;

Is there any way that I can automate this process so I don't need to repeat this cycles manually? I probably need to repeat this cycles hundreds of times. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExternalPrograms.html describes how to run external commands, like a.out, from within Mathematica and how to read in external files. Perhaps you could have a Do or While or For loop in Mathematica to control the repetition you desire

Comment: @Bill After reading this, I am still not sure how to run a.out within Mathematica exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`RunProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html) to run arbitrary executables.

Comment: Hi, I tried to create a Mathematica program under the same directory of the *.out file, and tried RunProcess["./a.out", "StandardOutput"], but it failed. Do you know what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Use `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]` before using `RunProcess`.

Comment: @Roman It works! Thanks!